# Powershell read from Excel and Insert into SQL database

Tags: sql-server, excel, powershell

I have an Excel file with structure

```
phone         | date       | vaccine | time | place
--------------+------------+---------+------+-------
+7xxxxxxxxxx  | 27.10.2021 | Pfizer  | 9:00 | XXX
```

I need insert data from all rows into a SQL Server database table for sending the notification to specific persons with phone number from first column.

For inserting the data into the SQL Server database, I use this code:

```
$xl = New-Object -COM "Excel.Application"
$xl.Visible = $true
$wb = $xl.Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\Documents\111.xlsx")
$ws = $wb.Sheets.Item(1)

for ($i = 1; $i -le 20; $i++) {{$insertquery="
>> INSERT INTO dbo.MessageOut(MessageTo,MessageText)
>> VALUES ($ws.Cells.Item($i, 1).Value,'Reminder that you recorded for vaccination on $ws.Cells.Item($i, 2).Value
>> Vaccine $ws.Cells.Item($i, 3).Value
>> Time $ws.Cells.Item($i, 4).Value
>> Place $ws.Cells.Item($i, 5).Value
>> Don't forget a passport')
>> GO
>> "}
>> Invoke-SQLcmd -ServerInstance 'SMS\SQLEXPRESS,49366' -query $insertquery -Database SMSserver
>> }
```

I need to read all rows in Excel file and write two values in SQL database - phone number from column 1 to MessageTo, and text message with values from columns 2-5 to MessageText. But when I enter code above I get an error in Russian, approximate translation is - "Invoke-SQLcmd : Link to remote function "System.__ComObject.Cells.Item" unacceptable. Name of column "System" not found.

Please help decide such task.